# CSS conflict - position:absolute in ExtJs Grid

Tags: css, extjs, grid, conflict

Recently I'd integrated ExtJs Grid into an existing webpage and resulted in a CSS conflict. I'd identified the conflicting CSS in my existing stylesheet. Unfortunately I cannot modify my current stylesheet since the entire website in built on top of that.

I have tried using the *ctCls*, *baseCls*, *bodyCfg*, *bwrapCssClass* and *bodyCssClass*, but didnt worked out as expected.

Below is the conflicting stylesheet of my existing website

```
div
{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
visibility: visible;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
white-space: nowrap;
position: absolute;
}
```

The style *position: absolute* is causing the conflict. I'd tried CSS overriding but is not working as expected.

Please note:
setting the style *position: relative* to every DIV tag in the rendered grid can fix the issue. I have mocked up that using the IE Developer Toolbar.

Can someone help me how can I set that, for the rendered Grid, so that I can successfully override the *position: absolute* of the master page CSS style, with *position: relative*.

Does anyone has faced similar issue? Is it possible for me to override the CSS successfully? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you provide a page with the grid. So that we can try to see it in firebug. tnx

Answer (score 2):

I don't think, that it's a good idea to set CSS styles in such a generic way on ALL `<div>`-elements on a page. But OK... You can try to override the settings using the following CSS rule:

```
.x-grid3,
.x-grid3 div {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: Nope! Its not working. I have tried with couple of other css classes also.
Is there any mechanism in CSS which allows to ignore a particular style position: absolute from the masterpage's stylesheet, while rendering? I have tried the !importance, but no use. :(

Comment: The flag is called `!important`. But you should use Firebug (or some other development tool) to check which styles are applied to an element and which have been overridden.

Comment: Hi thanks for the correction (!important). I managed to override the css by adding a style in the ext-all css file. 
'code'div{position: relative;} 'code'
But this only fixed grid's position issue. But has caused some font-family and font-size issues, since my maste style for DIV has those styles defined. To time being it fine. But, I'm looking for a better solution in parallel. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my web project and I've searched long time to find the solution. The problem is two elements are using the same Css in the same **frame**. So the best way to avoid the conflict is rendering your Grid Panel into another frame (always into the same page). You can use [Managed IFrame user extension](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71961-3.0.x-3.1.1-ux.ManagedIFrame-2.x) or [uxmedia](http://code.google.com/p/uxmedia/). I'm using uxmedia extension. To create an iFrame in uxmedia:

```
var htmlViewer = new Ext.ux.ManagedIFrame.Panel({  

    border  : false,

    title   : title,

    header: header,

    region:'center',

    iconCls : iconCls,

        // Here your Grid Panel comes within an url from server side
    defaultSrc : urlAddress
        });
```